# drag drop with chartJS works incorrectly

Tags: chart.js

I have a gantt chart with bars and I want to have a drag drop operation.
but dragData works incorrectly for some reason, throwing random bars on top without taking any action

[My gantt chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPwSi.png)

my goal is to move a bar to another line